# \maketitle Missing number treated as zero. Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). Undefined control sequence

Tags: titles

I edited as you mentioned but the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are placed as you mentioned from the beginning and still, the error exists.

---

I have the following error and I can't find the solution. Can anyone help me?
Here is a sample of my code:

```
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{plain}% Set page style to plain.

\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/.../Desktop/Manual/} }
\author{...}
\title{...}
\date{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
   \begin{titlepage}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command 
                                                    for the horizontal 
                                                    lines, change thickness 
                                                    here

    \center % Center everything on the page

    \textsc{\LARGE \textwidth ....}\\[1.5cm]
    \textsc{\Large ...}\\[0.5cm] 
    \textsc{\large ...}\\[0.5cm] 

    \HRule \\[0.8cm]
    { \huge \bfseries A guide of .....}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{center}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo}
    \end{center}
    \end{flushleft}

    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{center} \large
    \emph{Author:}\\
    A \texts{P} 
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    %~
\end{titlepage}
}
\makeatother
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Ε..}
    \vfill
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{home_page_gr}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new at Latex and I try to learn so I haven't mentioned any document class. How this line you tell me is an error from the time that this is a comment?

Comment: Ok i will edit this and delete this comment.

Comment: So, for the error '\maketitle' what can I do? Also, I edited and inserted the document class as '\documentclass{report}'.

Comment: @Sebastiano The comments are deleted, no worries :) The other is my problem right now.

Comment: @Ariadne No :( In the `\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}` you have one `%`. It is important to put four `%` one for every row.

Comment: Did this error require a number on '\maketitle'?

Comment: @JouleV Thank you so much! The error left from here, but the first page of my article with the Author name and the image of course with the Header is lost.

Comment: Where did you copy the code from?

Comment: It is not copied, it's from my former partner and I'm trying to make changes because this specific line is not working.

Comment: @Ariadne I don't like solving problems in comments, so I posted an answer.

Comment: Reusing code thatway is never a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Compilable (without errors) code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{plain}% Set page style to plain.

\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/.../Desktop/Manual/} }
\author{...}
\title{...}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command 

    \center % Center everything on the page

    \textsc{\LARGE ....}\\[1.5cm]
    \textsc{\Large ...}\\[0.5cm] 
    \textsc{\large ...}\\[0.5cm] 

    \HRule \\[0.8cm]
    { \huge \bfseries A guide of .....}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{center}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
    \end{flushleft}

    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{center} \large
    \emph{Author:}\\
    A \textsc{P} 
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    %~
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Ε..}
    \vfill
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{example-image-b}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

What I have changed:

1. To solve the main issue: I see that `\textwidth` in `\textsc{\LARGE \textwidth ....}\\[1.5cm]` is the problem. I don't really understand why it is there. Or do you want to add the current margin width?
2. In the original code, `Defines a new command` is recognized as a comment by the `%`, but `for the horizontal lines, change thickness here` is not. I decide to delete them :)
3. To solve error `Undefined control sequence`: I changed `\texts` (which is not defined) in `A \texts{P}` to `\textsc`. Well, P is already in uppercase, so this command is not necessary at all...
4. Of course I can't compile your document because I don't have images `logo` and `home_page_gr`, so I use `example-image-a` and `example-image-b` instead.

Comment: Very good, especially, for your item 2. :-)

Comment: The line \textsc{\LARGE \textwidth ...}\\[1.5cm] is having an error and I have inserted the package \usepackage{textcomp}. I am using \textwidth because I want my sentence to have the current margin. Where is the problem to this now?

Comment: I deleted the \textwidth line and solve the problem. I'm trying to make a space on this line because it's a huge proposal that goes 1 line down the header and the second line of the proposal is stuck with its top. If you compile this ' \textsc{\LARGE Foundation of Research and Technology}\\[1.5cm]' tell me how we can make it work in one sentence and center aligned, or in 2 lines with a tiny space between them.

Comment: @Ariadne Why don't you use normal \ \ without parameters?